# Disable IPv4 mapped IPv6

Tags: networking, ipv6

I run a service on IPv4, but sometimes, apparently randomly, it happens that the service uses TCPv6 sockets (I monitor it with `ss -s`).
I want to avoid it, disabling any IPv6 connection.

I tried to disable it putting in /etc/sysctl.conf :

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

and then restarting sysctl `sudo sysctl -p`.
However, it still happens that the service uses IPv6, though it is disabled:

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6
1
```

The only way I have found to work it out is to put down and up the interface

```
sudo ifconfig eth1 down
sudo ifconfig eth1 up
```

Note: no IPv6 address is assigned to any interface. Moreover, I cannot reboot the machine.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable IPv6 completely from the kernel by editing /etc/default/grub. Find the line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
```

Replace it with:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="ipv6.disable=1"
```

Then run:

```
update-grub
```

And reboot.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't reboot the machine.

Comment: I think you also need `net.ipv6.conf.eth1.disable_ipv6 = 1` in sysctl.conf; I would also add all the other known interfaces. You should probably also comment out ::1 in /etc/hosts if you have one...although I doubt this is the source of your problems.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking out of the box here because of the no reboot constraint. Maybe if you use some kind of container, docker or lxc for example, for your service allow you to disable ipv6 for the container.

Docker daemon for example has an "--ipv6=true|false" flag

Comment: The point is that I am using a server that is not mine, so I need to be as minimally invasive as possible.I would appreciate a lot if you could address me to a tutorial or guide for implementing your suggestion.